# How to Check existing column in sqlite

Tags: objective-c

HI friends i learnt sqlite recently.  i am using below code for name is exist or not in sqlite  but i am not getting result. please help me.
BOOL columnExists = NO;

```
        sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;
        NSString *upperString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:exptypeFld.text];
        NSString* changeString = [upperString uppercaseString];
        NSLog(@"changeString %@",changeString);
        [upperString release];
        const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT expensetype from expensetypes where upper(expensetype) = '%@'",changeString] UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"char is %s",sqlStatement);
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Same........");
            columnExists = YES;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `sqlite3_step` to actually execute the query. Also, is the database connection open at this point? You should also finalize the statement when you are done with it. And you shouldn't use string formats to bind values to a query. You should use `sqlite3_bind_xxx`.

```
NSString *upperString = exptypeFld.text; // no need for the string format
NSString* changeString = [upperString uppercaseString];
NSLog(@"changeString %@",changeString);

const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT expensetype from expensetypes where upper(expensetype) = ?";
NSLog(@"char is %s",sqlStatement);

sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
     sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 1, [changeString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_step(sqlStatement); // you should check the result of this too
}
sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
```

This code assumes the database has already been opened.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to use existing classes to access SQLite databases. You can find an example I wrote here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite

It has wrapper classes for accessing SQLite in a more traditional database way that I feel makes things easier.